# Use `tf.summary.tensor_summary` to visualize a tensor in projector plugin

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

is it possible to use `tf.summary.tensor_summary` to save a tensor in a summary, and then visualize it with the projector-plugin?

I know, there are workarounds to use a assign a tensor to a variable and save it with a `Saver`, but since `tensor_summary` allows me to add an additional `SummaryMetadata` I thought it could be possible.